# Enable eslint only for edited files

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

Recently, I configured eslint one of my projects. This project was consisting of hundreds of files, as soon as I configured eslint starts showing errors in all files.

IMO, eslint traverses through all js files, which is not required currently. Is there any way we can limit eslint only for edited files?

Comment: what do you mean by "edited files"? I mean, for example, you run lint, which files should it check...?

Comment: Suppose there are 100 of files, which may contain eslint errors/warnings but I want eslint to track only changed files.

Answer (score 44):

`eslint --fix $(git diff --name-only HEAD | xargs)`

Comment: I used this, but added a `**/*.js` to not have it lint things like `docker-compose.yml`: `eslint --fix $(git diff --name-only HEAD **/*.js | xargs)`

Comment: Just a small comment the `**/*.j` should be inside quotes:

`eslint --fix $(git diff --name-only develop '**/*.js' | xargs)`

Comment: Facing issue when the commit includes deleted files
`No files matching the pattern "app/views/home/MoEvents.js" were found.
Please check for typing mistakes in the pattern.`

Comment: @ArjunNayak To fix `No files matching the pattern "./src/DELETED.js" were found`, you can add `--diff-filter=d` to the git diff command like this: `eslint $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | xargs)`. This should probably be added to the answer.

Answer (score 24):

1. If you want to lint staged and edited files, use:

   ```
   eslint $(git diff --name-only HEAD | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$' | xargs)
   ```

   or run it with yarn if you want to use it in the terminal:

   ```
   yarn run eslint $(git diff --name-only HEAD | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$' | xargs)
   ```

   Explanation:

   - `git diff --name-only HEAD`: name of edited files
   - `grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$'`: Filter js and jsx files. You can add your file formats here.
   - `xargs`: get names as arguments
2. Also you can use [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) library to lint staged files. It's useful if you want to run it before each commit and make sure your repo always remains pretty and linted.
   Read more about it [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html).
3. If you want to lint last committed files, use:

   ```
   eslint $(git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1 | grep -E '\.(js|jsx)$' | xargs)
   ```

Comment: I don't think you need `| xargs`

Answer (score 7):

The answer is: do not run Eslint globally for all files.
I think what you want is to prevent the offending code to be commited to repository (of course, it's already there, commited before linting was introduced, but you want to prevent *new* commits to be made that contain eslint errors).
This means that it makes sense to run Eslint only on those files, that have changes in them and are about to be commited to repo, i.e. staged files.
There is a package that does exactly that, [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged).
In your package.json, you add a configuration like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint --fix",
},
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js,mjs,cjs,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}": [
     "npm run lint"
  ]
}
```

Then when you run `npm run lint-staged`, only the files that are staged will be passed as argument to lint command, so only those  will be linted.
Usually it makes sense to combine lint-staged with [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) to automatically run linting and some other checks like formatting as a pre-commit hook  (i.e. each time when you try to make a commit those checks will be executed)
This way you can make sure that no code that contains errors will be commited.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe ESLint caching is what you need?

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#caching

Comment: This can insulate the other directory to validate but I want to track only the changed files.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this and it works like a charm

```
LIST=`git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep .*\\.js | grep -v json`; if [ \"$LIST\" ]; then eslint --fix $LIST; fi
```

I've added it to the package.json as a script under the name of `lint:git` and now I execute it with `yarn lint:git`

Taken from https://gist.github.com/oroce/11282380#gistcomment-2741146

Answer (score 5):

The following command is very convenient for me:

```
git diff --name-only | xargs eslint --fix
```

It applys `eslint --fix` for each row of the `git diff --name-only` output via `xargs` command.

Answer (score 1):

similar to @ELCAPITANBETO 's feedback

we can do

`eslint -c eslintrc.js $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB master | grep  -E \"(.js$|.ts$|.tsx$)\")`

https://gist.github.com/seeliang/0f0de424d1cdc4541c338f4ee93b7e6a

Answer (score 0):

For larger files where doing a pull-request with thousands of line changes isn't practical, you can use `lint-diff`

This tool just lints the lines that were changed:

https://github.com/grvcoelho/lint-diff