# How to get prettier errors in terminal when starting react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

Disclaimer, I am not using `eslint-plugin-prettier`, I do not want to run it as a linting task, I want linting and formatting to stay separated. Plus it affects the performance of these steps a little.

I am wondering, how to get prettier formatting warnings/errors as I get when using eslint. When eslint finds and issue, the build from create-react-app shows me the errors in my terminal. Prettier does not.

What I tried was:

```json
"start:dev": "yarn start & yarn prettier-watch",
"prettier-watch": "onchange \"**/*\" -- prettier --check --config .prettierrc.json --ignore-unknown {{changed}}"
```

The `prettier-watch` script works if I run it manually, but it doesn't work when I let the start script run it. What happens is that the output from prettier shows for a split second and then disappears when the build is done.

Reason why I am doing this: other collaborators might not do auto-formatting using their editor, and I don't want to show errors everywhere in the IDE, just a kind reminder in the terminal that what they changed could/should be formatted with prettier. I am also adding this check as a step in the CI pipeline.

I wonder how eslint is configured to integrate with the build of create-react-app and output those errors, would be helpful.

Comment: You could run ESLint only on changed files. That way you can use the eslint-plugin-prettier without it complaining your whole project doesn't comply. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511168/enable-eslint-only-for-edited-files

Comment: @3limin4t0r I understand. I am already doing this with eslint. The reason why I am not using that plugin is because I am trying to avoid coupling formatting with linting. Plus, prettier formatting is much faster than linting from eslint and using that plugin I am bottlenecking my formatting with eslint. This was a recommendation from a talk I attended and also saw on a blog. I really wish I understood how eslint integrates their errors into the build process of `create-react-app` so I can do the same for prettier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the single ampersand to run the two commands in parallel, as it requires UNIX-like environment (not specified in the question, but being Node.js not UNIX-specific I can assume there may be Windows-based collaborators). Also pay attention that NPM, Yarn and similar tools may try to mitigate the differences between shells by allowing only a subset of operators.

There are many npm packages that tackles this issue, e.g.:

- [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) with the `--parallel` option (or shortly as `run-p`):

  ```json
  "start:dev": "npm-run-all --parallel start prettier-watch",
  ```

  Note that, despite the name, it supports `yarn` correctly;
- [`concurrently`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently):

  ```json
  "start:dev": "concurrently \"yarn:start\" \"yarn:prettier-watch\""
  ```

  or with explicit command

  ```json
  "start:dev": "concurrently \"yarn start\" \"yarn run prettier-watch\""
  ```

  Note that the double quotes (that needs to be escaped) are required.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I wanted from what I read on the npm packages docs.